# How to Format formula Field result in a Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I make a Formula Field named GrandTotal in Crystal Reports.

Currently, its formatting resembles `2,223,223`.  I would like it to resemble `2223223`.

Comment: select number field drug and drop ,bind the data later ,right click and format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you don't need to create a `formula field` to do this.  Simply select the desired field located in the `details` section, then choose Insert | Summary Field...

The `summary field`'s location (i.e. `report footer`, `group footer`) will determine the calculation that is performed.

If the field is in the `report footer`, the calculation will be `Sum({table.field})`.

If the field is in the `group footer`, the calculation will be `Sum({table.field},{table.groupingField)`.

To change the formatting of any numeric field (`formula`, `summary`, or otherwise), simply click the appropriate toolbar button(s):

[image]

Comment: Page Footer: there are five different formatting formula types: background color, clamp page footer, reset page number after, suppress blank section, and underlay following sections.  The formula lets you insert the data condition for true.